# Serialize and Desserialize json value to list in C#

Tags: c#, json, list

so for this work i need to take objects in json to a list, the objects are customers that contain only name, email, and phone number.

i tried a few times but failed, if someone can show me or explain i will be really greatfull.

```
namespace customers_manager
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class Customer
        { 
            public string name { get; set; }          
            public string email { get; set; }
            public int number { get; set; }
        }

        static List<Customer> Datac = new List<Customer>();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Console.WriteLine("New Customer data:");
        Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
        cliente.name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Email: ");
        cliente.email = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Number: ");
        cliente.number = Console.ReadLine();
        Datac.Add(customer);
        Console.WriteLine("Finish, Press enter to leave");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Before this when i try to Serialize i only find errors

Comment: same I got error when I send data to my MVC controller and get

Comment: You forgot to post the code you use to kick off serialization as well as the resulting errors

Comment: but I fixed it using another method in my js file and controller

Comment: See this link for help: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingcollections.htm

Comment: If you mean by "errors" your shown code doesn't compile then yes code belongs into methods and yours is directly in a class. To get better help try to show something that compiles and shows your serialization code.

Comment: While improving the question: consider the suggestions from [ask]. If not already, maybe also take the [tour]. Definitely consider the suggestions on how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Newtonsoft.Json library to serialize and deserialize JSON. Install the NuGet package.

Example of usage:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // You'll need this to bring the namespace in scope

List<Cliente> Dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(response);
```

Where response is a string that contains the JSON serialized object list.

To serialize the list to a JSON string:

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dados);
```

Comment: Why do you inexplicably declare Dados to be static? Why do you initialize it with an empty list, only to turn around and reassign the result of the deserialization?

Comment: @Fildor It does technically show how to serialize and deserialize to/from JSON. So it could be helpful and solve the asker's problem, even though it's not customized to the question, does some things poorly, and it was answered before waiting to see what the asker did wrong.

Comment: @mason its obvious the person who asked is a begginner programmer so i just copied his line of code. It makes no sense to do that, you're right

Comment: @Fildor while i am an experienced programmer i am new to stackoverflow, just trying to answer some easy questions to get started

Comment: @mason That's why I didn't dv or flag or anything. Just felt a little ... I don't know.

Comment: @JordiColl Yeah that's ok, then. Usually, answering low-quality questions (like this one is) is more or less frowned upon. Maybe my gut feeling betrayed me on this one. No offense.

Comment: @JordiColl Remember you can't control what code others write. But you can control what you write. If you're going to show somebody how to do something, show them how to do it right. Don't let them go on with issues in their code without speaking up, and don't leave bad code around presented as a solution to a problem - others are likely to just copy your code without understanding that it's bad. Be a positive force for the community! Remember - you can and should edit the code in your answer.

Comment: @mason i edited the answer, thanks for the tips! appreciated. I will try  my best to provide better answers in my next contribution to the community